# Getting datetime object from a string given by a user

Tags: php

The problem is to get datetime object from a string when the user provide date in any of the following format(dd-mm-yyyy , yyyy-mm-dd) my result should be in (yyyy-mm-dd). My function is as follows as:

```
public function dateOfBirth($date){
    $date_format = strtotime($date);
    $result = new \DateTime('@'.$date_format);
}
```

It successfully returns date as (yyyy-mm-dd) when the date is in (yyyy-mm-dd) format but returns the following error when user provides date in(dd-mm-yyyy) format

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (@) at position 0 (@): Unexpected character
```

I need date return in (yyyy-mm-dd) format when user enters any of the above format

Comment: Why are you putting an `@` at the beginning

Comment: Without the `@` that code works fine

Comment: The code you posted is the same as `new \DateTime($date)`. [`DateTime::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) use the same engine to [parse the date strings](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Comment: @RiggsFolly: The `@…` notation is valid to initialize the datetime object with a unix timestamp.

Comment: @lxg Always a good day when I learn something. Thanks

Comment: @AJRJ: The code as posted should work. I assume that you have some other code (not visible here) which breaks the DateTime initialization. If not, can you please provide some example input to your function? Also, what do you get when dumping `$date_format`?

Comment: as already siad. `@´ ist for creating from a unix timestamp. Since strtotime() retuns timestamp as int -> it does work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me, Thank you all for your response,

```
public function dateOfBirth($date){
    $date_format = strtotime($date);
    $result = (new \DateTime())->setTimestamp($date_format);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function getFormattedDate($date)
{
    $dateObj = new DateTime($date);

    return $dateObj->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

call the function:

```
print_r(getFormattedDate('23-12-2017'));
print_r(getFormattedDate('2016-02-20'));
print_r(getFormattedDate('15-05-2018'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$one = new \DateTime('2018-08-12');
$two = new \DateTime('12-08-2018');
var_dump($one, $two);
```

in php 5.6+ both a valid DateTime objects. So now you can return it in desired format

```
$one->format('Y-m-d'); // echoes 2018-08-12
$two->format('Y-m-d'); // echoes 2018-08-12
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a combination of `date()` and `DateTime` as below;

```
public function formatDate($date){
    $dateObj = new DateTime(date($date));

    return $dateObj->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    $in1 = '2018-08-20';
    $in2 = '20-08-2018';
    print_r(userDate($in1)); // 2018-08-20
    print_r(userDate($in2)); // 2018-08-20
    print_r(userDate(time())); // 2018-08-20

    function userDate($date)
    {
        if ($result = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)) return $result->format('Y-m-d');
        if ($result = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date)) return $result->format('Y-m-d');
        // ...
        $dt = new \DateTime();
        if ($result = $dt->setTimestamp($date)) return $result->format('Y-m-d');
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What’s the point of this code? Any explaination? How does it answer the question?